# Login authentication failed

Tags: authentication, phpmyadmin

I have been using phpmyadmin web-login for several years and never had any issues. Recently I haven't been able to login although I am able to login to our server by FTP. My mate is able to use the web-login. I have tried login in with Android phone, HP laptop, desktop (both win 7 prof.), several different browsers Chrome, Opera, Safari, explorer and firefox.

The message I get is: `Authentication required. The server http://www.example.com:80 requires a username and password.` The server says: `phpMyAdmin localhost`.

When I enter username and password the window disappear and reappears after a few seconds. I can see the status goes from connecting to waiting just before the window reappears.

No changes to the server has been made recently.

Any suggestions on how to solve the issue?

Comment: So your mate, using the same username and password you're trying, is able to connect, but you're not? What happens if you try to log in on his/her machine or he/she logs in on yours? Any hints in the webserver error log?

Comment: I'm able to logon on her maschine but neither of us on mine maschines.

Comment: There is no error in the log. just looks like I refreshed the page.